# How to write a common Xpath or CSS for the multilanuage ecommerce site for the below element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasses/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Choose Lenses &amp; Buy</a>

//*[@id="content-column"]/div[3]/div/div/div[9]/a[1]

<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasses/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button" data-type="eCommerce">Choose Lenses</a>
//*[@id="content-column"]/div[3]/div/div/div[9]/a

<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasses/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Choose Lenses</a>
//*[@id="content-column"]/div[3]/div/div/div[8]/a

<a rel="nofollow" href="/brillen/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Kies uw glazen en koop</a>
//*[@id="content-column"]/div[3]/div/div/div[9]/a

<a rel="nofollow" href="/briller/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Velg glass og kjøp</a>

//*[@id="content-column"]/div[3]/div/div/div[8]/a

<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasogon/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Välj glas och köp</a>
//*[@id="content-column"]/div[3]/div/div/div[8]/a
```

I have a Multilanguage ecommerce site I need to identify a element for a same product which is across the 6 sites in different language.

Comment: You need to share relevant HTML and Page url if it's public

Comment: <a rel="nofollow" href="/glasses/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Choose Lenses &amp; Buy</a>,<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasses/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button" data-type="eCommerce">Choose Lenses</a>,<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasses/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Choose Lenses</a>

Comment: <a rel="nofollow" href="/brillen/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Kies uw glazen en koop</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/briller/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Velg glass og kjøp</a>
<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasogon/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Välj glas och köp</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP has share this HTML :

```
<a rel="nofollow" href="/glasses/starlet/lens-selector?sku=25666847" class="btn btn-block btn-xl btn-primary buy-btn frames-buy-online-button">Choose Lenses &amp; Buy</a>
```

and **5 more anchor tag** like this.

A common xpath locator would be :

```
//a[@rel='nofollow' and contains(@href, '/starlet/lens-selector') and contains(@class, 'frames-buy-online-button')]
```

Comment: <a class="ss-nav-primary__link" href="/glasses/all-glasses"  title="Glasses" trackaid="menus-glasses">Glasses</a>
<a class="ss-nav-primary__link" href="/brillen"              title="Brillen" trackaid="menus-glasses">Brillen</a>
<a class="ss-nav-primary__link" href="/briller/alle-briller" title="Briller" trackaid="menus-glasses">Briller</a>
<a class="ss-nav-primary__link" href="/glasogon/sok-bage"    title="Glasögon" trackaid="menus-glasses">Glasögon</a>

Comment: If i skip one attribute its not working i tried this //a[@class='ss-nav-primary__link' and contacins(@trackaid,'menus-glasses')

Comment: contains is it a typo or intentionally you have written ?

Comment: No i tried by missing one attribute as there is no common in href  is there any other way ?

Comment: No you have to depend on attributes. Class and trackaid should work..